# Draw triangles around screen

Tags: unity, geometry

I am trying to draw triangles around the screen something like this:

[image: 3 grey triangle wedges radiating out from a central point[1]]

This is my script which can draw 6 triangles but I am not sure how to expand it to draw more like 8 or 10 triangles. Any help is appreciated

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

    public class BackgroundScript : MonoBehaviour
    {
        [SerializeField]
        private Material darkMaterial;
        [SerializeField]
        private Material lightMaterial;

        [SerializeField]
        private float triangleDistance = 50;

        private GameObject[] triangles;

        void Start()
        {
            CreateBackground();
        }

        private void CreateBackground()
        {
            float w = triangleDistance * Mathf.Tan(30 * (Mathf.PI / 180));

            triangles = new GameObject[6];

            for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
            {
                GameObject backgroundTriangle = new GameObject();
                backgroundTriangle.name = "triangle " + i;
                triangles[i] = backgroundTriangle;

                MeshFilter mf = backgroundTriangle.AddComponent<MeshFilter>();
                MeshRenderer mr = backgroundTriangle.AddComponent<MeshRenderer>();

                Mesh mesh = new Mesh();
                mesh.vertices = new Vector3[] { new Vector3(0, 0, 0), new Vector3(triangleDistance, 0, w), new Vector3(triangleDistance, 0, -w) };
                mesh.normals = new Vector3[] { new Vector3(0, 1, 0), new Vector3(0, 1, 0), new Vector3(0, 1, 0) };
                mesh.triangles = new int[] { 0, 1, 2 };
                mf.mesh = mesh;

                mr.material = i % 2 == 0 ? darkMaterial : lightMaterial;

                backgroundTriangle.transform.Rotate(new Vector3(0, i * 60 + 30, 0));
                backgroundTriangle.transform.SetParent(this.transform);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: There is clearly a `6` twice in your code...Also you don't need to create a new mesh for every triangle. You could just push all the triangles into one mesh for each material.

Comment: @Sidar Even if you change the 6 to 8 or 10 nothing really happens. I believe that is not the issue

Comment: Oh but it is, you should also consider how the angles are calculated.

Comment: @Sidar Yeah definitely angles

Answer (score 1):

eight triangle:

[image: eight triangle]

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

    public class BackgroundScript : MonoBehaviour
    {
        [SerializeField]
        private Material darkMaterial;
        [SerializeField]
        private Material lightMaterial;

        [SerializeField]
        private float triangleDistance = 50;

        private GameObject[] triangles;

        void Start()
        {
            CreateBackground();
        }

        private void CreateBackground()
        {
            float w = triangleDistance * Mathf.Tan(22 * (Mathf.PI / 180));

            triangles = new GameObject[8];

            for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
            {
                GameObject backgroundTriangle = new GameObject();
                backgroundTriangle.name = "triangle " + i;
                triangles[i] = backgroundTriangle;

                MeshFilter mf = backgroundTriangle.AddComponent<MeshFilter>();
                MeshRenderer mr = backgroundTriangle.AddComponent<MeshRenderer>();

                Mesh mesh = new Mesh();
                mesh.vertices = new Vector3[] { new Vector3(0, 0, 0), new Vector3(triangleDistance, 0, w), new Vector3(triangleDistance, 0, -w) };
                mesh.normals = new Vector3[] { new Vector3(0, 1, 0), new Vector3(0, 1, 0), new Vector3(0, 1, 0) };
                mesh.triangles = new int[] { 0, 1, 2 };
                mf.mesh = mesh;

                mr.material = i % 2 == 0 ? darkMaterial : lightMaterial;

                backgroundTriangle.transform.Rotate(new Vector3(0, i * 45 + 30, 0));
                backgroundTriangle.transform.SetParent(this.transform);
            }
        }
    }
```

---

also you can create this shape by shader.

[The Book of Shaders Shapes Tutorial](https://thebookofshaders.com/07/)

To create a new shader, either choose `Assets > Create > Shader > Unlit Shader` from the main menu, or duplicate an existing shader and work from that. The new shader can be edited by double-clicking it in the Project View.then copy below shader to it:

```
 Shader "Custom/ProceduralTriangle"
{
    Properties
    {
        _numberOfTriangle("numberOfTriangle",Int) = 8
    }
    SubShader
    {

        Pass
        {
            CGPROGRAM
            #pragma vertex vert
            #pragma fragment frag

            #include "UnityCG.cginc"

            struct appdata
            {
                float4 vertex : POSITION;
                float2 uv : TEXCOORD0;
            };

            struct v2f
            {
                float2 uv : TEXCOORD0;
                float4 vertex : SV_POSITION;
            };

            v2f vert (appdata v)
            {
                v2f o;
                o.vertex = UnityObjectToClipPos(v.vertex);
                o.uv = v.uv;
                return o;
            }

            int _numberOfTriangle;

            fixed4 frag (v2f i) : SV_Target
            {
     float2 st = i.uv;
        float3 color = float3(0,0,0);

        float2 pos = float2(0.5,0.5)-st;

        float r = step(length(pos),0.);
        float a = atan2(pos.x,pos.y);

        float f = cos(a*_numberOfTriangle+_Time.y);
        float c = smoothstep(f,f+0.02,r);
        color = float3(c,c,c);

        return float4(color, 1.0);
            }
            ENDCG
        }
    }
}
```

then create a material and use this shader.

[image]

this is simple fragment shader if you want to create geometry you can use geometry shader.I will update my question and explain this.

Comment: I made an empty gameobject. Add this to it but nothing happens

Comment: @user113599 shader don't work in empty object try it again by using Plane object.if you like to use this shader in gameObject first you should create a shader and attach it to material then use it.

Comment: Hmm would be great if you can add a geometry shader as well